# During proof R is uncountable set from Abbott's Understanding Analysis

Tags: analysis

I don't understand red line parts. I dont know why the assumtion that the list in (1) contains every real number leads to the conclusion that the intersection n to infinite number In equal to empty set. 
Please explain why... I will really appreciate it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Right before the part that you underlined, they show that if $x$ is in that list (1), then it is not in the infinite intersection $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$. By construction, the list (1) contains all real numbers, so all real numbers are not in $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n$, or in other words, this infinite intersection is empty.

Comment: so you mean before underline, "We  now consider ..." parts states that if x is in that list (1) then it is not in the infinite intersetction In ?

Comment: so x0 can be any kind of real number from the list ?

Comment: @KwangiYu Exactly

Answer (score 1):

Every real number is assumed to among the $x_n$'s, but we constructed the $I_k$ intervals so that $x_n\notin \bigcap_kI_k$ holds for all $n$ (because, by construction $x_n\notin I_{n+1}$).

So this intersection contains no real numbers. So it is empty.

Comment: x0 can be any kind of real number from the list 1, so any real nubmer from the list cannot be in infinite intersetction In.  Is it right ?